# How Old Is My Meat Slicer?

Tags: equipment

I just purchased this Berkel GC for $50, which to me is a steal, it was rusty and crusty as can be, running poorly and smoking. The blade moved but it has a ton of resistance, I've taken everything apart, cleaned up all the grease, rust, and dirt and will get replacement parts once I start working again.  I plan on rebuilding and restoring it sometime in Dec.

However my biggest gripe is I don't know the age of this thing. Anyone have a clue? I want to say it's 1940's tech, but i'm not sure. There isn't much if any documentation of these older Berkel slicers at all.

Here is a pic of it.
[image]
[image]

It came with everything, sharpening stones and catch platter. FYI, it's in my bedroom now, it was outside because I had to strip the paint and also use phosphoric acid to remove the rust.

Here is the serial and motor #.
[image]

[image]

original file for motor specs.

https://farm5.staticflickr.com/4579/38288529602_c0f7734dec_o.jpg

Comment: The motor looks 1940s. I don't get any hits on that model number though. Any patent numbers anywhere on the unit? Ah, here's an NP76510 motor dated **1943**: https://www.ebay.com/itm/5KC47AB490D-G-E-Vintage-Motor-N-P-76510-/332021029025 (top-left number on motor label)

Comment: Sorry no potent numbers, the spec plate is missing.

Comment: I checked also. That GE end cap. WW2 threw Korean war. Do not mess that end cap up! That motor can still be rebuilt.  But no parts are listed for it as being sold by G.E. today. I checked there parts catalog. But a motor shop can still rebuild them some as long as windeings are not burnt.

Comment: That sounds about right, How can I prevent windings from becoming burned up?

Comment: Do not over load the motor. So it heats up. Make sure the cutter is spinning. The bushings & brush's can be replaced. Armiture needs cleaned at time of brush replacement. With a hack saw blade snapped of. Is the way we use to do it. Bushings you can go to thick wall then ream out to size. Shaft cam be polished in the motor . On a lath. Just polished. When new bushings are put in. Take to a motor shop today to do. Does not need often done. Use motor till it needs repair first. With the cap hole that motor probably needs a drop of oil put in there. Those motors had bushings not bearings.

Comment: If the blade is not turning freely, fix what is keeping it from doing so before attempting to run it again. Your motor smoking means it is overloaded - it might or might not already be permanently damaged. Having a competent motor shop (one that could do a rewinding if necessary) examine it is a good idea. If any motor windings have lost their insulation integrity against another (from age or running it overloaded too long), that will not "fix itself" - a shorted turn in a winding makes the whole motor act like a shorted high current transformer. Fire and shock hazard.

Comment: BTW, this might just be a diy.stackexchange topic ...

Answer (score 2):

That is hospital white enamel paint. So WW2 to 1960 would be a good guess. Look at the tag. I can not read it. Run that on a search. Give you a better idea. Those names can still be found. Also the red tag. Does the motor have a name & number on it? With that you can do a number check often to get it down to year motor was made. With luck. Any serial number on it those can be ran on a search. Threw company records if it is found. Or post good photo's of the tags. & numbers.

Comment: Added info if that helps.